# Creating flags for calculating rolling averages in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a data sheet which looks like:

```
year   month
2017   2017-01
2017   2017-02
2017   2017-03
......
2018    2018-04
2018    2018-05
```

Note the column month contains text string. I need to create a new column flag in excel which filters which months are to be used in calculating rolling 12M averages for current month and which months are to be used for calculating rolling 12M averages for previous year.
For example today's date is 5/24/2018, so month 2018-05 will be marked as "current". months between 2018-04 to 2017-05 will be marked as "both". month 2017-04 will be marked as "previous". Rest all months will be marked as NA.  My final data should look like this:

```
year   month       flag
2017   2017-01      NA
2017   2017-02      NA
2017   2017-03      NA
2017   2017-04      Previous
......
2018    2018-04     Both
2018    2018-05     Current
```

I am having trouble implementing this logic in excel as the column month is a text string and simply using IF condition doesn't works for me. Any leads on this is appreciated.

**Edit:**
I tried converting the months to a number by using `=DATEVALUE(B2 & "-01")`.
I stored the number for current month in a variable `curr`.
Now I am using the following formula `=IF(B22=curr,"Current", IF(B2=curr-395,"Previous","Both"))`.
This creates the flag column which I require although there's still an issue based on whether the month has 30 or 31 days. Any solutions for this please?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Reading [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: To start the formula `=DATEVALUE(B2 & "-01")` will turn 2017-01 into a real date.

Comment: I was looking for a way currently to convert the months column to some integers so that I can use modulus 12 afterwards to add the flag. Not able to convert those months to number yet

Comment: If you edit your question with your thoughts on how the mod 12 will work and what part you're stuck with the close votes will probably be removed. Sorry, the site likes to see the working out of questions - I guess it's more of a "nudge me in the right direction" forum.

Comment: `=RIGHT(B2,2)*1` should get you a month number

Comment: `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),RIGHT(B2,2),1)` will return a date for the first day of the month `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),RIGHT(B2,2)+1,0)` for the last day of the month

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `DATDIF`.

`=DATEVALUE(B2 & "-01")` will give you the first of each month in column B.

To return the month number use `=DATEDIF(C2,TODAY(),"m")` where column C holds the `DATEVALUE` formula.  This will return 0 for this month, 1 for last month... 13 for April 2017.

Now check to see if the count of months = 0 then it's *current*, if it's greater than 11 it's *NA*, otherwise it's *both*.  `=IF(D2=0,"Current",IF(D2>11,"NA","Both"))`

**... Edit ....**

That's wrong - forgot the "Previous" and "Both" isn't 12 months ....

```
=IF(D2=0,"Current",IF(D2>13,"NA",IF(D2=13,"Previous","Both")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As considering your column month format = "YYYY-MM"  this code may be helpful
this is Excel function, to use it you need to save this function in the module and use it. `

```
Function MyDateCal(cell As Range) As String
Dim YearCurrent, YearCell, monthCurrent, MonthCell As Integer
Dim cellVal As String, DiffMonth As Integer[![enter image description here][1]][1]
cellVal = cell.Value
MyDateCal = "NA"
'cellVal = Cells(1, 1).Value
YearCurrent = Year(Now())
monthCurrent = Month(Now())
YearCell = CInt(Left(cellVal, 4))
MonthCell = CInt(Right(cellVal, 2))

DiffMonth = 12 * (YearCurrent - YearCell) + (monthCurrent - MonthCell)

If DiffMonth = 0 Then
MyDateCal = "Current"
ElseIf DiffMonth > 0 And DiffMonth <= 12 Then
MyDateCal = "Both"
ElseIf DiffMonth = 13 Then
MyDateCal = "Previous"
End If

End Function
```

`

[image]